# Cisco triangle network with static routing not working

Tags: cisco

I have this network

[image]

when the network tries to communicate with the routers it fails.

I have already tried everything in my power without success.
how to assign ip addresses in routing

[image]

I have been trying for a long time to make static routing work but without success

- I am using router 2911
- I am using the 2960 switch

here is the cisco file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qRY1WU2RvFbIdxuhzYSe_vFXf1uE2sy3/view?usp=sharing

configuration router informatica

```
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up









Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!



Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.17.2.1 255.255.255.252
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/2
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.224
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/2
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.224
Router(config-if)#
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up

Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/1
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/1
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.17.1.1 255.255.255.252
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/1
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.17.1.1 255.255.255.252
Router(config-if)#








Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!



Press RETURN to get started!



Press RETURN to get started!



Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#








Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!



Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#
Router(config)#








Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!
```

configuration router RRHH

```
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up









Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!



Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.17.2.1 255.255.255.252
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/2
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.224
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/2
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.16.10.1 255.255.255.224
Router(config-if)#
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up

Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/1
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/1
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.17.1.1 255.255.255.252
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#
Router(config-if)#exit
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/1
Router(config-if)#ip address 172.17.1.1 255.255.255.252
Router(config-if)#








Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!



Press RETURN to get started!



Press RETURN to get started!



Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#








Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!



Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#
Router(config)#








Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Press RETURN to get started!
```

configuration router produccion

```
Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.





















Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.





















Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#ip route 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.224 172.17.1.1
Router(config)#
%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down









Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.












%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/0, changed state to down

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/0, changed state to up

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to down

%LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1, changed state to up










Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.













Router>enable
Router#
Router#configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#
Router(config)#interface GigabitEthernet0/0
Router(config-if)#








Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.





















Router con0 is now available






Press RETURN to get started.
```

Comment: Please add the routers' configurations (output of `show run`) to your question as text, using the editor's `{}` preformat function. We're not likely to download some dubious binary file from the Internet nor is everyone using packet tracer.

Comment: Ok, modified and fixed

Comment: What we need is the results from the `show running-config` and the `show ip route` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You have added just a single static route to *router produccion* - you need to add a static route to each network that is remote to a router, so two routes for each of your routers.

A router needs to have a route to the destination in order to forward a packet. Without a route the packet can only be dropped. Routers learn routes in three ways:

1. directly attached networks are added automatically
2. static routes configured manually by the admin
3. dynamic routes learned from adjacent peers by routing protocols like OSPF or BGP